# How Can you use java11 and with java11 compiled libraries on gluon Mobil?

Tags: java, android, gradle, gluon

It seems wierd to me that you can must use  Java11 for Gluon.attach but you can not build a apk because of retrolambda issues, because they are compiled with java 11.

But with JDK1.8 you can build a apk but can not use gluon.attach instead i use gluon.charm.plugin.

Do i need to have a special gradle configuration to generate a apk with gluon.attach ?

this is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.7.0'
         classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.12'


    }
}



plugins {

    id 'java-library'
    id "java"
    id "eclipse"

    id 'application'



}

apply plugin: "org.javafxports.jfxmobile"





repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()

    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'

    }

}
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
    main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources"
}

mainClassName = 'de.test.main.App'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {

    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'



    //GLUON
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-core', version: '3.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-glisten', version: '5.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq.attach', name: 'display', version: '4.0.2'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq.attach', name: 'util', version: '4.0.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq.attach', name: 'orientation', version: '4.0.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq.attach', name: 'magnetometer', version: '4.0.1.1'
    //END






    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.11'

    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm', version: '5.0.1'

}





jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'

        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'icon.png'

        }   
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Or is this feature only for iOS ?

Comment: Gluon Attach is for Java/JavaFX 11+. It doesn't work with JDK 1.8, and the `jfxmobile` plugin, where you have to use `Charm Down` libraries.

Comment: @JoséPereda Hello José! What's the current status with Java 11 for mobile now? :) I have heard that Gluon have finnish it, but I can't se a stable version of it. Is it still under development?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson See https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples, Java 11+, JavaFX 11+, on Linux, MacOS and iOS are working perfectly fine. Android is coming along, Windows will be later.

Comment: @JoséPereda Great! Will it be some kind of a installation wizard for this software? I'm mean that if lots of people are going to use it, the it need to be simple to install that software. Like a Eclipse plugin from Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson while the "old" Gluon IDE plugins get updated, you can start with the Gluon [Client Maven archetypes](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-archetypes).